# In Meteor is there a way to import app details after an initial app setup?

Tags: meteor

What I'd like to do is on the first load of my app, ask the user some questions. The answers they provide will be used to set the organization information that appears throughout the app instance.

For instance when the app loads the first time I'll ask; "What is your organization name?", "What is your organizations phone number?", "What is your Stripe secret key" and more questions like these. I'll then use that information to populate receipts and contact information that appears throughout this app instance.

Normally I'd use the settings.json file to populate this information and make it easy to drop in these pieces from anywhere in the app. I don't want to expect that the user even knows how to use Meteor and so I don't want to use the settings.json file.

Comment: Are you talking about a framework that you are developing or something that is really user facing? If it's the latter you would definitely attach it to the user object and not save it in some file. You can make parts of that variable 'unaccessible' to the user and therefore he won't know what you see about him

Comment: Well. I have an app which is basically a donation portal for a non-profit. I want to make this app accessible to anyone. If you've ever setup Wordpress you'll know what I'm getting at. The first time you run it you get some questions. I don't expect users to be using my organizations instance of the app, rather they'd deploy their own.

Answer (score 0):

Save those values to the user profile. If 1 organization has many users & they all share these values, create a collection like `organization` and save the values there.

Comment: Ok. I think this is probably the right way. I'm just uncertain about the security here. How do I let only the server (not any user) have access to some of the data. There is plenty of settings I never want the users to see (after the admin initially enters it). Some of the data could be open to everyone, and I know how I'd handle that.

Comment: same as any other collection, only send what you need to send to the client. for example, you've got a stripe key, that can live on the server unless the admin requests it.